# Why array[length] returns the first element of the list?

Tags: javascript, arrays

as i know one can return the length of an array either by using

`array.length`

or

`array["length"]`

but omitting the quotes like this

`array[length]`

will return the first element of the array
This is the actual code:
var list = [5, 7, 10]; then in the console list[length] returns 5, and no i don't have iframe or frames in the window, so window.length or just length return 0 in the consol.

Comment: Congrats, you found the global `length` property of the `window` object.

Comment: It is easy because windows have a property of length and it depends on the length of the window (let's call it browser tab) you are in, it will return different number, it is number of frames (maybe iframes) of a page, in your case, it returns 0

Answer (score 3):

You are using [`window.length`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/length).

> Returns the number of frames (either `<frame>` or `<iframe>` elements) in the window.

```js
var array = [21, 22];

console.log(length);
console.log(window.length);
console.log(array[length]);
```

```html
<iframe></iframe>
```

Comment: it is the same scenario of the last statement console.log(array[length]); , but you are saying that i am using window.length which i am not

Comment: here is my code: var list = [5, 7, 10]; then i type this in the console : list[length]; which returns 5

Comment: @Hassan, please watch the difference now with an iframe. both values of `length` are now one.

Comment: I get it now, Thanks  Nina :)

Answer (score 1):

Length equates to numerical 0 which returns the first element if it exists.

Numerical 0 since you have a browsing context (Document) and no other contexts.

Be cognitive of other environments such as nodejs, NW.js etc. which may exist and may differ from the browser context.